# How to catch and handle error response 422 with Redux/Axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I have an action making a `POST` request to the server in order to update a user's password, but I'm unable to handle the error in the chained catch block.

```
return axios({
  method: 'post',
  data: {
    password: currentPassword,
    new_password: newPassword
  },
  url: `path/to/endpoint`
})
.then(response => {
  dispatch(PasswordUpdateSuccess(response))
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('ERROR', error)
  switch (error.type) {
    case 'password_invalid':
      dispatch(PasswordUpdateFailure('Incorrect current password'))
      break
    case 'invalid_attributes':
      dispatch(PasswordUpdateFailure('Fields must not be blank'))
      break
  }
})
```

When I log the error this is what I see:

[image: Error Logged]

When I check the network tab I can see the response body, but for some reason I can't access the values!

[image: Network Tab]

Have I unknowingly made a mistake somewhere? Because I'm handling other errors from different request fine, but can't seem to work this one out.

Comment: axios & catch & error.response

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Axios is probably parsing the response. I access the error like this in my code:

```js
axios({
  method: 'post',
  responseType: 'json',
  url: `${SERVER_URL}/token`,
  data: {
    idToken,
    userEmail
  }
})
 .then(response => {
   dispatch(something(response));
 })
 .catch(error => {
   dispatch({ type: AUTH_FAILED });
   dispatch({ type: ERROR, payload: error.data.error.message });
 });
```

From the docs:

The response for a request contains the following information.

```js
{
  // `data` is the response that was provided by the server
  data: {},

  // `status` is the HTTP status code from the server response
  status: 200,

  // `statusText` is the HTTP status message from the server response
  statusText: 'OK',

  // `headers` the headers that the server responded with
  headers: {},

  // `config` is the config that was provided to `axios` for the request
  config: {}
}
```

So the `catch(error => )` is actually just `catch(response => )`

EDIT:

I still dont understand why logging the error returns that stack message. I tried logging it like this. And then you can actually see that it is an object.

```
console.log('errorType', typeof error);
console.log('error', Object.assign({}, error));
```

EDIT2:

After some more looking around [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) is what you are trying to print. Which is a Javascipt error object. Axios then enhances this error with the config, code and reponse like [this](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/lib/core/enhanceError.js).

```js
console.log('error', error);
console.log('errorType', typeof error);
console.log('error', Object.assign({}, error));
console.log('getOwnPropertyNames', Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error));
console.log('stackProperty', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(error, 'stack'));
console.log('messageProperty', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(error, 'message'));
console.log('stackEnumerable', error.propertyIsEnumerable('stack'));
console.log('messageEnumerable', error.propertyIsEnumerable('message'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, I went through the repository code which helped. Ultimately I logged the object and was able to see the response object and handle the data. 

additional code:
`let e = {...error}`
`switch (e.response.data.type)`

Answer (score 70):

Example

```
getUserList() {
    return axios.get('/users')
      .then(response => response.data)
      .catch(error => {
        if (error.response) {
          console.log(error.response);
        }
      });
  }
```

Check the error object for response, it will include the object you're looking for so you can do `error.response.status`

[image]

https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#handling-errors

Comment: Exactly what i needed! Thx

Comment: Yes! Accessing err.response gets what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Here is the proper way to handle the `error` object:

```
axios.put(this.apiBaseEndpoint + '/' + id, input)
.then((response) => {
    // Success
})
.catch((error) => {
    // Error
    if (error.response) {
        // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
        // that falls out of the range of 2xx
        // console.log(error.response.data);
        // console.log(error.response.status);
        // console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
        // The request was made but no response was received
        // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
        // http.ClientRequest in node.js
        console.log(error.request);
    } else {
        // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
        console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
    console.log(error.config);
});
```

Origin url https://gist.github.com/fgilio/230ccd514e9381fafa51608fcf137253

Answer (score 10):

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/register', {
    username : 'test'
}).then(result => {
    console.log(result.data)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response.data)
})
```

add in catch 
geting error response ==> `err.response.data`

Answer (score 3):

I was also stumped on this for a while. I won't rehash things too much, but I thought it would be helpful to others to add my 2 cents.

The `error` in the code above is of type `Error`. What happens is the [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/toString) method is called on the error object because you are trying to print something to the console. This is implicit, a result of writing to the console. If you look at the code of toString on the error object.

```
Error.prototype.toString = function() {
  'use strict';

  var obj = Object(this);
  if (obj !== this) {
    throw new TypeError();
  }

  var name = this.name;
  name = (name === undefined) ? 'Error' : String(name);

  var msg = this.message;
  msg = (msg === undefined) ? '' : String(msg);

  if (name === '') {
    return msg;
  }
  if (msg === '') {
    return name;
  }

  return name + ': ' + msg;
};
```

So you can see above it uses the internals to build up the string to output to the console.

There are great [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) on this on mozilla.

Comment: This helped me figure out my issue thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The only thing what helped me was the following:

```js
axios.put('/api/settings', settings, {
  validateStatus: status => status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 422
})
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66285529/5849569

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline if else statement like so:

```
.catch(error => {
    dispatch({
        type: authActions.AUTH_PROCESS_ERROR,
        error: error.response ? error.response.data.code.toString() : 'Something went wrong, please try again.'
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend handling errors via Axios interceptors, individually for each case scenario:

```
// interceptor to catch errors
const errorInterceptor = (error) => {
  // check if it's a server error
  if (!error.response) {
    console.log(' API | Network/Server error')
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }

  // all the error responses
  switch (error.response.status) {
    case 400:
      console.error(error.response.status, error.message)
      console.log(' API | Nothing to display', 'Data Not Found')
      break

    case 401: // authentication error, logout the user
      console.log(' API | Please login again', 'Session Expired')
      localStorage.removeItem('user')
      break

    case 403:
      console.error(error.response.status, error.message)
      console.log(' API | Access denied', 'Data Not Found')
      break

    case 404:
      console.error(error.response.status, error.message)
      console.log(' API | Dataset not found', 'Data Not Found')
      break

    case 422:
      console.error(error.response.status, error.message, error.response.data.detail)
      console.log(' API | Validation error', 'Unprocessable Content')
      break

    default:
      console.error(error.response.status, error.message)
  }
  return Promise.reject(error)
}
```