# Axios does not handle 500 from POST after OPTIONS returned 200 for CORS

Tags: javascript, axios

## Problem

Axios does not handle 500 as expected. Followed the way [Axios error handling](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors) provides, but it is not working.

The POST is sending username/email and password but the password is intentionally set to an incorrect one to test the error handling. If the correct password is set, works with no problem.

```
    axios.post(
        config.apiGateway.URL + ".../signin",
        payload
    ).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        if(response.status == 200){
            console.log("Login successfull");
            this.setState({token: response.data.JWT_TOKEN});
        } else {
            console.log(response.status)
            this.setError()
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        this.setError()
        console.log(error)
        if (error.response) {
            console.log("--------------------------------------------------")
            // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
            // that falls out of the range of 2xx
            console.log(error.response.data);
            console.log(error.response.status);
            console.log(error.response.headers);
        } else if (error.request) {
            console.log("*************************")

            // The request was made but no response was received
            // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
            // http.ClientRequest in node.js
            console.log(error.request);
        } else {
            console.log("++++++++++++++++++++++++")
            // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
            console.log('Error', error.message);
        }
        console.log(error.config);
    })
```

### Result

It is expected **if (error.response)** part is executed but actually **else if (error.request)** is executed.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://***-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/***/signin' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Login.js:73 Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
Login.js:82 *************************
Login.js:87 XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
```

In Chrome developer tool, OPTIONS method returns 200 as below.

```
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
access-control-allow-methods: GET,OPTIONS,POST,PUT
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-length: 0
content-type: application/json
date: Wed, 16 Jan 2019 01:32:48 GMT
status: 200
via: 1.1 ca8c566e53d4556421f22afbb9802d0c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-apigw-id: Tkp2JEBmIAMFROA=
x-amz-cf-id: HXEEGh3TUcOckodVBKKoA1PVpg6h7UB5Ui3F1svTxpMYovB8Dt7rqQ==
x-amzn-requestid: a2144ccd-192e-11e9-9b6f-2dcad2a22d99
```

POST method returns 500 as expected.

```
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 
Remote Address: 54.230.245.164:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

### Environment

axios 0.18.0 with Google Chrome 70.0.3538.77 in Ubuntu 18 LTS.

### Question

Please suggest how to handle 500 properly.

### Research

[How to catch and handle error response 422 with Redux/Axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798451/how-to-catch-and-handle-error-response-422-with-redux-axios) appears to have the same issue of error being set to a stack trace and response seems not get populated.

> EDIT:
>   I still dont understand why logging the error returns that stack message. I tried logging it like this. And then you can actually see that it is an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your question simply...

> why isn't `error.response` present?

If so, the reason is because the resource handling your `POST` request does not respond with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, even though it does for the pre-flight `OPTIONS` request.

Due to CORS policy, your client-side code is therefore **denied access** to the HTTP response and hence, `error.response` is not defined.

In your error handler, you can assume that an empty `response` property equates to a network-level problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding the header to 500 response fixed the problem and MDN CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) shows it too.