# How do I handle errors in a redux action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, redux, axios

```
import axios from "axios";
export const createNewUser = (newUser, history) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    await axios.post("http://localhost:9090/users/register", newUser);
    history.push("/login");
    dispatch({
      type: "GET_ERRORS",
      payload: {}
    });
  } catch (err) {

    dispatch({
      type: "GET_ERRORS",
      payload: err.response.data
    });
  }
};
```

This is my action,I have a form where I bind the inputs to my state and I'm calling the action when I submit the form as such:

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newUser = {
      "username": this.state.username,
      "fullName": this.state.fullName,
      "password": this.state.password,
      "confirmPassword": this.state.confirmPassword
    };
    console.log(this.props)
    this.props.createNewUser(newUser, this.props.history);
  }

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(nextProps)
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }
  }
```

This is all covered in a tutorial for spring boot and react, I believe that I followed it exactly however I am not getting the same results. I even copied the code as it is in the tutorial. When I click submit I see a 400 error in the console, but the state ( errors) stays undefined.

This is what my backend returns when I checked with debugger:

```
<400 BAD_REQUEST Bad Request,{password=Password must be atleast 6 characters, fullName=Please enter your full name, username=username is required},[]>
```

Comment: What does your mapStateToProps look like?

Comment: have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/38798652/9623287