# Sending error status(res.status) and message(res.json) both simultaneously in express

Tags: node.js, express, axios, response, status

I'm trying to do **an error management in express** as per the form input from frontend. I saw that either I can send `res.status(401)` as error code or `res.json({})` as sending error message but not both. What should I do below here to **send both simultaneously?**

```
app.post('/verifyOTP', (req, res) => {
  const hash = req.body.hash;
  let [ hashValue, expires ] = hash.split('.');
  let now = Date.now();
    if (now > parseInt(expires)) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Timeout. Please try again' })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do this

**what enables send to send object** :- *When the parameter is an Array or Object, Express responds with the JSON representation:* for more reference [express docs for send](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendhttps://)

How can i combine `.status and .send?`:-*Sets the HTTP status for the response. It is a chainable alias of Node’s response.statusCode.* for more reference  [express status docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.status)

```
app.post('/verifyOTP', (req, res) => {
  const hash = req.body.hash;
  let [ hashValue, expires ] = hash.split('.');
  let now = Date.now();
    if (now > parseInt(expires)) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Timeout. Please try again' })
    }
})
```

Comment: I tried it and doesn't seem to work at all. I can only get either one of them

Comment: did you tried this in Postman?
ofcourse in browser you will only get `error message`.

Comment: oh yes it is working in postman. But how can I `console.log` or display the error code and message in frontend with axios I tried `data.data.error` in response cycle and I cant get the error message. Any suggestion what should I do?

Comment: when you say console.log just have to write console.log('text') and it will be shown to your in the backend of your server.
i haven't worked with axios though but this can help https://itnext.io/javascript-error-handling-from-express-js-to-react-810deb5e5e28, however, i would have tried this like keeping a variable for status code and based on condition i would have send it with res.send({error : nam_of_var, msg:'timeout').

Comment: I tried this and this working without using axios `res.status(500).send({status:500, message: 'internal error', type:'internal'}); 
`

Comment: for axios https://stackoverflow.com/a/38798652/13126651, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60825383/13126651,https://stackoverflow.com/a/60869154/13126651

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html):

```
res.status(400).send({ error: 'Timeout. Please try again' })
```

Comment: I tried that and doesn't seem to work at all. I can only get either one of them